# Jackson 2.0 compatibility with Jackson 1.x

Tags: jackson

First I do not speak very good english, i will try to explain of the best way possible.enter code here

I've created a service architecture that using services applications. This architecture uses jackson 2.5.2 for serializacion/desealizacion
JSON object. If one service application uses jackson 1.8 for generate JSON object response, the architecture try to deserialize that objet throws the next error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-String when  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

I don't know if the reason for the error is that the json response contains fields of type String  and as well one field of JSONNode type

Is possible to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

While Jackson 1.x and 2.x are not directly source or binary compatible, they do produce and consume exactly same JSON. So your error message does not suggest version incompatibility, but rather some other type of a problem.